# How to downgrade or install older or specific version of node using Homebrew?

Tags: node.js, excel, macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I'm new to brew, to be honest. I want to use an earlier version of the Node. The current version I have is `node@14`.

The Version I've been trying to install is `node@9.10.0`, I tried installing it using **Brew**. `brew install node@9.10.0`

Online, [I have followed instructions here](https://jasonfleetwoodboldt.com/2014/06/25/how-to-install-old-versions-of-node-and-npm/)

but it keeps throwing me an error, I'm not sure If I'm doing anything wrong here.

```
Warning: No available formula or cask with the name "node@9". Did you mean node, nodenv, node@12, node@10, node@14 or ode?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly-named formulae were found:
node ✔       nodenv       node@12      node@10      node@14      ode
To install one of them, run (for example):
  brew install node ✔
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I tried Updating brew and I have also tried `brew doctor` to resolve any kind of complications.

I have also tried uninstalling `Node` completely and installed it using `Brew` but any of the methods doesn't seem to work. Should I use a different subcommand instead? Is there a completely different method I should try?

I'm running macOS Bigsur 11.6 and Homebrew 3.2.16

Answer (score 1):

First do: `brew search node` and tell me what you get
If you get the node version you want do:
`brew install node@availableversion`

Comment: No, Unfortunately,  I'm not getting node@9.  It's showing this :(                                                       ==> Formulae
libbitcoin-node     node-sass           node_exporter       ode
llnode              node@10             nodebrew
node                node@12             nodeenv
node-build          node@14             nodenv
==> Casks
nodebox                                  nodeclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can download from nodejs website:

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v9.10.0/

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find for mac version tho

Comment: You need to download darwin version

Comment: this is not the answer of the question... "using homebrew"

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

1. `eval "$(nodenv init -)"`
2. `node -v`
3. `brew unlink (the node version you see)`
4. `nodenv install -l`
5. `nodenv install (the node version you want on the list)`